# Toolbar hides when I End the project from XCode

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nstoolbar

I'm building an application in Xcode with a toolbar that is not visible at launch and must be accessed by the menu bar.  However, as soon as I un-checked the "Visible at Launch" the toolbar disappeared and I don't know how to get it to show itself again so I can customize it without using command-z.  I know there must be a way so I can customize it anytime I want.  Thanks!

Comment: Toolbar of XCode or your App?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya The app's toolbar.  I want the toolbar not to be visible at launch, but I want to be able to edit the toolbar from Xcode.  When I uncheck visible at launch, select something else, the only way for me to get back to the toolbar's settings is command+z.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya here is an imgur album of my problem, hope it helps make what I'm trying to say clearer (sorry) http://imgur.com/a/3NGVX

Comment: +1 for osx question and a valid issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing nothing wrong; this is a problem with Xcode.

To edit the toolbar, it has to be set to "Visible At Launch". When you're done working with the toolbar, just uncheck it. When you want to work with the toolbar, check it. You don't need to rely on undo or anything because you can just select the `NSToolbar` in Interface Builder even if it isn't shown.

[image]

Or, if you don't want to do that, just get a reference to the `NSToolbar` using an `IBOutlet` and call `-setVisible:NO` at the beginning of every launch.

Answer (score 0):

> as soon as I un-checked the "Visible at Launch" the toolbar
>   disappeared and I don't know how to get it to show itself again

In the Interface Builder **Check "Visible at Launch"** and it will come back.

Comment: I know that, but I _don't_ want it to be visible at launch.  I want to be able to edit it from Xcode, and have it not be visible at launch.

Comment: So when do you want to be launch?

Comment: I want the toolbar to open when I click the "Show Toolbar" in the menu of the app.  This all works perfectly, but I cannot edit the app's toolbar from Xcode.

Comment: ok, i see. What happens when you do "Show toolbar" and quit the app from xcode? And one thning extra, please align all the buttons to same size, it is looking BAD.

Comment: It doesn't do anything when I show toolbar in the app and the click stop.  And I know it looks terrible, it used to be a much smaller window but I'm about to add ~30 more buttons, so I needed to resize the window.

Comment: Surely a strange issue, i cant solve it now.  If you can wait til monday and mail me the proj, then i can help you.